# Como criar campo de tags igual do stack overflow?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou desenvolvendo um site de receitas e um dos campos para cadastrar a receita, são as tags.

Eu queria colocar uma função igual ao do stackoverflow, um input que conforme eu vou digitando ele traz as tags e, quando clico, vai adicionando nesse input, para depois alimentar a tabela. E também queria a possibilidade de inserir uma nova tag se ela ainda não existir

Eu tenho 3 tabelas, a da receita, a de tags e a que vincula a tag com a receita

```
receitas
idreceita|nome
1        |Como fazer arroz

tags
idtag|nome
2    |fim de semana

receita_tag
id|idreceita|idtag
1 |   1     |  2
```

Estou usando PHP e Mysql

Comment: Se você estiver utilizando Jquery pode dar uma olhada [nessa lib](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/), ela ajudaria a fazer o desejado

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa pergunta ( https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/107651/input-do-tipo-text-similar-ao-sistema-de-tags-do-stack-overflow?rq=1 ) e vê se a resposta te ajuda. Pax.

Comment: A única coisa que fez foi as tabelas? E o php?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam criei um form em php que insere as infos na tabela receitas, mas a tag está apenas assim <input type="text" name="tag">. Vou ver esse outro link

Comment: Uma forma mais simples para iniciar é criar um multiselect com as que existe e um campo texto para novas